# How to make laravel and wordpress to make use of single user table (Wordpress should use laravel users table)

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to merge Laravel and Wordpress together in one project. The way I want it to work is, for Laravel to handle the Database Interactions and complex iterations going on on the site, while Wordpress is used to handle the static contents, pages and all. Using this approach, I want both of them to share a users table for login on both ends.

I saw this package on packagist jgrossi/corcel by Junior Grossi, and its doing a great job, getting the posts and all. There is the tutorial working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together,
but I'm yet to find one that actually binds both framework+cms to one authentication table seamlessly.

I need ideas on this...

Answer (score 1):

Try reversed: `laravel` use the `wordpress`'s user table.

Set the same `db connection`, then change the `App\User` to work with the Wordpress's user table.

Also: Laravel uses `bcrypt` and Wordpress uses `md5` so you have to change one to the another. I recommend to use `bcrypt`